# Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap' with module other than commonjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I use React with Typescript, but cannot use React Bootstrap with a module other than `commonjs`.

I first install `react-bootstrap` package:

```
$ npm i react-bootstrap
```

And then write the code to use it, for example,

```
// src/index.tsx
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

But compiling it by `npx tsc` get an error `Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap' or its corresponding type declarations.` When I googled about this issue, I found that `react-bootstrap` has its own types (so I do not need `@types/react-bootstrap`).

If I set `module` in `tsconfig.json` to `commonjs`, then I can compile it correctly.

Why cannot I use `react-bootstrap` however? Are there other ways to use React Bootstrap together with Typescript (and with modules other than `commonjs`)?

The minimal example here:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "type": "npx tsc --noEmit",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

`src/index.tsx`:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Then run

```
$ npm run type

> foo@1.0.0 type /home/bar/src/foo
> npx tsc --noEmit

src/index.tsx(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! foo@1.0.0 type: `npx tsc --noEmit`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the foo@1.0.0 type script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bar/.npm/_logs/2020-07-04T12_11_17_351Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try once like this `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';`

Comment: It also fails with the same error (just replacing 'react-bootstrap' with 'react-bootstrap/Button').

Comment: Please share your demo code on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-almeida-2kntm

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean npm modules cache using
   `$ npm cache clean --force`
2. Delete **node_modules** by `$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` or delete it manually
3. Install npm modules `npm install`

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you too.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not fix the problem. After all, I am using Docker, so it does not seem that I have something wrong with cache.